# A loyal traitor

Tags: word, wordplay, lateral-thinking, story, english

Two countries are at war, Albekistan and Uzbania. The leader of the Albekistanian army asks, "Who **___** me?". The Uzbanian army's leader replies, "I **___** you!" She is promptly shot by her own army for being a traitor. Ten days later, the Uzbanian army intercepts and decrypts the following communications between an Albekistanian general and the Albekistanian president:

```
Dear President Parthizi,

Our spies have been unable to determine the reason why General Grimmith was shot.
Evidence shows that nearly all Uzbanians consider her a traitor, but our records indicate
that Grimmith remained steadfastly loyal. In any case, we must comb our ranks rigorously
for possible infiltration - our upcoming military action is of critical importance to
winning this war.

Regards,
General Gorlathon
```

After six more months of war, the remorseful Uzbanian warriors are routed because of the loss of morale and the death of their most competent general.

**___** consists of three words. What were the words, and why was General Grimmith shot?

Comment: I swear I've come across a puzzle almost exactly like this before somewhere on Puzzling... I can't put my finger on it but it rings a faint bell... It's going to nag at me until I either find a duplicate or solve this one! :)

Comment: @Stiv I guess great minds think alike, since I came up with this on my own :P

Comment: Maybe it was a dream I had... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the three words were

> **will come to** or some variation of that. (From OP, the intended phrase was **will fight with**, but the explanation remains the same.)

The conversation would go thusly:

> Gorlathon: Who **will come to** me?
>  Grimmith: I **will come to** you!

In Grimmith's view, all she is doing is

> declaring her intention to start a battle with Gorlathon.

But in the Uzbanian soldiers' view, her comment might be misinterpreted as meaning

> that she will cross over and join the other side i.e. "come to" Albekistan. Thus, they would believe her to be a traitor and promptly shoot her.

Previous incorrect attempts:

> - **will surrender to**: Grimmith wouldn't say she surrenders because she's loyal and competent.

Comment: Incorrect - somebody who is loyal would never say rot13("V jvyy fheeraqre gb lbh!"), nor any variation of that

Comment: Oh, I just had another idea, gimme a moment...

Comment: Correct! The precise intended answer was rot13(V "jvyy svtug jvgu" lbh, orpnhfr vs lbh "svtug jvgu" gur rarzl, lbh pbhyq rvgure or svtugvat ntnvafg gurz, be svtugvat ba gurve fvqr nf n genvgbe)